# Pipeline sync fails when using JFrog-Pipelines

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

While using JFrog Pipelines, and I make changes to the `pipeline.yml`, I see that intermittently pipeline sync takes a long time without clear reason. Any reason why this happens?

We time out and then re-force the Sync manually as a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow few of the simple tips for faster sync response:

1. To cleanup un-used branches of your repository which is used in your gitRepo resource
2. To not create gitRepo typed resources without any branch pattern specified. (For eg: You can provide your working branch for the same)

Comment: Thanks - pls update when the new release is released.

Comment: There is now a significant performance improvement in 1.24.0 version of Pipelines.